# C# Linq orderby only works for fields returned?

Tags: linq

I want to do a Linq query that joins three tables, but only returns data from two of them (the third is only joined for ordering purposes). I'm trying to order by columns that aren't in the output of the produced query, but they seem to be ignored:

```
var records = from q in _pdxContext.Qualifier
      join aql in _pdxContext.ApplicationQualifierLink on q.Id equals aql.QualifierId
      join qt in _pdxContext.QualifierType on q.QualifierTypeId equals qt.Id
      where SOME_LIST.Contains(aql.ApplicationId)

      orderby aql.Sequence

      select new Qualifier 
      { 
          Id = q.Id,
          QualifierType = new QualifierType 
          { 
              Id = qt.Id, Value = qt.Value
          }
      };
return records.Distinct().ToList();
```

The output SQL from this does NOT have an ORDER BY clause.

If I change the orderby to read like so:

```
orderby q.Id
```

... then the output SQL has the order by clause.

Does Linq ignore orderby statements when the mentioned columns aren't used in the output (as appears to be the case here)? If so, how do I order by columns not in the output?

Comment: What LINQ are you using, LINQ to SQL, EF 6.x, EF Core 2, EF Core 3? Without knowing, I would speculate that `Distinct` removes the `order by` and if you placed it after the `Distinct` it may preserve it (also, `Distinct` on `Qualifier` is suspect...)

Comment: The Distinct call is the issue. I could call Distinct after ToList, but after distinct there are maybe 0 - 6 records, before distinct there might be millions. So I really don't want to return millions of records from the database.

Comment: @NetMage EF Core 2.

Comment: Why not call `OrderBy` after `Distinct`?

Comment: @NetMage Distinct is indeed the issue. See my first comment. Any idea how I can use distinct and not lose the order, AND not return too many records from the database (See my first comment).

Comment: Is EF Core 2 not translating `Distinct` to SQL?

Comment: @NetMage Distinct returns 0 - 6 records, without it there might be millions. That's a lot more than I need to return from the database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205881/discussion-between-netmage-and-developer-webs).

Comment: I suggest you to ordering after listing your result it will be take fast performance 
like .ToList().OrderBy(x=>x.QualifierType.Id);

Comment: @AkbarAsghari The field I want to order by is not selected and not part of the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is an SQL limitation. The error from the SQL Server engine:
"ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified."
So, as written, I can't do what I want to do.

I ended up using:

```
using (var cnn = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
{
    string sql = @"select
            min(q.Id) Id, q.QualifierTypeId, q.QualifierTypeId, min(q.AcaId) AcaId,
            q.QualifierTypeId Id, qt.Value
        from
            qdb.Qualifier q
            inner join qdb.QualifierType qt on qt.Id = q.QualifierTypeId
            inner join ApplicationQualifierLink l on l.QualifierId = q.id
        where   l.ApplicationId in (" + string.Join(",", applicationIds) + @")
        group by q.Text, q.QualifierTypeId, qt.Value";

    qualifiers = cnn.Query<Qualifier, QualifierType, Qualifier>(sql,
        (qualifier, type) =>
        {
            qualifier.QualifierType = type; return qualifier;
        }
    ).ToList();
}
```

Note: When you attempt to use order by and distinct as in my original clause, no error is given, entity framework silently discards the order by without any error.

Comment: Yeah, in EF Core 3.1 you can use groupby instead of distinct, then an aggregate function in the orderby and select afterwards, which SQL will accept, but it doesn't seem possible in EF 2.